# Learning React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have used observables in Angular, but I am having an issue in finding good examples on how to uses observables with React using Javascript. My end goal is to use hard coded data in a service.ts example

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface Volunteer {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  totalHoursLogged: number;
}

const tempVolunteers: Volunteer[] = [
    { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', totalHoursLogged: 85 },
];

export const getAllVolunteers = (): Observable<Volunteer[]> => of(tempVolunteers);
```

I want to make a list component to build the mock data as it is push from the observable.

I would export the react component into the App.tsx and display the 
mock data

If anyone knows of good resources or has any advice, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: The question is too broad and it's unclear what the problem is. Import `getAllVolunteers` and subscribe it. RxJS is just a library, you can use it anywhere. It's conventionally used with Angular because its API already deals with observables. React has different lifecycle and doesn't benefit much from observables for data binding out of the box.  Any way, you can start with https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable for RxJS or https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react for Mobx.

Comment: So its like I would need to import ether redux or mobx to use observables?

Comment: You can use them as is. An observable is just an object that has `subscribe` method. But you may need additional libraries to make them useful with React.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example (without Typescript for simplicity):

1. source file:

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

const tempVolunteers = [
  { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', totalHoursLogged: 85 },
];

export const getAllVolunteers = of(tempVolunteers);
```

2. React app file:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  getAllVolunteers,
} from '../RxJS';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    list: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {

    getAllVolunteers.subscribe((item) => {
      this.setState({
        list: [...this.state.list, ...item],
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          { this.state.list
            .map(({ firstName, lastName, totalHoursLogged }) =>
              (
                <div key={lastName}>
                  {`${firstName} ${lastName} - ${totalHoursLogged}`}
                </div>
              ),
            )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I am trying this with stackblitz.com IDE with React and Javascript, but I getting an error. Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined.                  
  `componentDidMount() {
    getAllVolunteers.subscribe((item) => {
      this.setState({
        list: [...this.state.list, ...item],
      });
    });
  }`

Comment: I think you have some problem with import getAllVolunteers. import {
  getAllVolunteers,
} from '../RxJS';

Comment: Ok, I need to point to the name of the file.  ```import { getAllVolunteers }  from 'name';```

Comment: You can create file getAllVolunteers.js in the same folder as App.js and import { getAllVolunteers } from './getAllVolunteers.js';

Comment: Thanks I was able to get the list to display now I just need to break it into smaller parts and put into components and also get it to work with TypeScript. Thank you for your help!